# Awk replace not working in "if" statement

Tags: unix, awk

I'm trying to replace a specific column in a file, let's say the third column in `test.txt`.

Create `test.txt`:

```sh
echo "1 2 -1" > test.txt
echo "3 4 +1" >> test.txt
```

If I do a simple replace, it works:

```sh
awk '$3="cows"' test.txt

1 2 cows
3 4 cows
```

However, if I use a conditional to vary the output, I get nothing:

```sh
awk '{
if ($3 == "+1")
     $3="cows";
else if ($3 == "-1")
     $3="sheep";
}' test.txt
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks!

Comment: The `print` statement.

Comment: Your input uses `+1`. Your awk uses `1`. Does that explain anything?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out John3136, I fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk programs are composed of conditions and actions, in the form `condition { action }`.

Awk has a default action, which is to print the current line.

In your first program the assignment is a *condition*, not an *action*, since there are no curly braces. Therefore the default action is executed.

In your second program, you have defined an action, which replaces the default action. Therefore, the `print` is not executed anymore, and you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks!  That was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You guys are right, here's the correct formatting.

```
    awk '{
    if ($3 == "+1")
         $3="cows";
    else if ($3 == "-1")
         $3="sheep";
    print
    }' test.txt
```